$f \in C([0,1]): \displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x)(P(x))^m\,dx =0$ for any nonnegative integer $m$ and second-degree polynomial $P$. Show that $f(x) = 0.$

Let $f(x)$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ and $\displaystyle\int_0^1
 f(x)(P(x))^m\,dx =0$ for any nonnegative integer $m$ and any
second-degree polynomial $P$.

Show that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1].$
Does the result in $(1)$ still hold if we replace second-degree polynomial $P$ with first-degree polynomial $P$ in the hypothesis?


I'm working on this problem but have struggled to solve it. After asking around and exploring various ideas, I managed to construct a proof for question $(1)$ that makes sense to me (described below). However, I am still stuck on question $(2)$, whose answer is yes.
The construction of $P(x)$ in my proof for $(1)$ requires that it is a second-degree polynomial. Since $m$ can be chosen arbitrarily, I considered setting $m = 2k$ and choosing $P(x)$ such that $P(x)^2 = (x- a)(b-x) + 1$. However, this construction seems problematic because it requires $(x- a)(b-x) + 1$ to be a perfect square for $a,b \in [0,1]$, which doesn’t seem possible. I would greatly appreciate any advice or insights on this problem.
Thank you!

Proof (question 1).
Suppose that $f(x) \neq 0$ for some $x = c \in [0,1]$. Without loss of generality, assume that $f(c) = \epsilon >0$.
Due to continuity of $f(x)$ at $c$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$ for all $x \in (c -\delta, c+ \delta)$. Since $f(c) - f(x) \leq |f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$ and $f(c) = \epsilon$, it follows that $f(x) >0$ for all $x \in (c -\delta, c+ \delta)$. Thus, there exists $a,b \in (c -\delta, c+ \delta)$, $a \neq b$ such that $f(x) > 0$ for $x \in [a,b]$.
Let $P(x) = (x- a)(b-x) + 1$. It is clear that $P(x) \geq 1$ for $x \in [a,b]$ and $0< P(x) < 1$ for $x \in [0,a) \cup (b,1]$.
Thus, $$\begin{align}I = \int_0^1f(x)P(x)^m\,dx &= \int_0^{a^-}f(x)P(x)^m\,dx + \int_a^bf(x)P(x)^m\,dx + \int_{b^+}^1f(x)P(x)^m\,dx.\\&\geq \int_0^{a^-}f(x)P(x)^m\,dx + \int_a^bf(x)\,dx + \int_{b^+}^1f(x)P(x)^m\,dx.\end{align}$$Taking the limit of both sides as $m \to \infty$, we have $\displaystyle\int_0^{a^-}f(x)P(x)^m\,dx \to 0$ and $\displaystyle\int_{b^+}^1f(x)P(x)^m\,dx\to 0$ since $0 <P(x) < 1$ for $x \in [0,a) \cup (b,1]$.
On the other hand, since $P(x)$ is a second-degree polynomial, we know that $I =0$. Thus, $$\int_a^bf(x)\,dx \leq 0,$$contradicting our earlier result that $f(x) >0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. It follows that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

It is enough if the hypothesis holds for $P(x)=x$. Standard application of Weirstarss Theorem.

@geetha290krm Hi, thank you! I'm sorry to say that I'm not familiar with this theorem. I'm reading up on it, but I'd love to hear if there is another way without using this theorem.

Your proof of $1.$ is cute $(+).$ You actually need that the assumption holds for an infinite sequence of positive integers $m.$

Consider the case $2.$ Then
$$\int\limits_0^1f(x)(x+1)\,dx =0=\int\limits_0^1f(x)x\,dx $$
By subtracting we get
$$\int\limits_0^1f(x)\,dx =0\quad (*)$$ Moreover, by assumptions we have
$$\int\limits_0^1f(x)x^n\,dx=0,\quad n\ge 1\quad (**)$$ Combining $(*),$ $(**)$ and applying linearity we obtain
$$\int\limits_0^1f(x)Q(x)\,dx=0 $$
for any polynomial $Q(x).$ In particular the equality holds for $Q(x)=P(x)^m,$ where $P(x)$ is a polynomial of the second degree. In this way we are reduced to the case $1.$

Thank you very much!
